# Simple significant usage of '/M' multi-line address suffix?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

For GNU `sed` v4.2.2-7, `info sed` says:

```
'/REGEXP/M'
'\%REGEXP%M'
     The 'M' modifier to regular-expression matching is a GNU 'sed'
     extension which directs GNU 'sed' to match the regular expression
     in 'multi-line' mode.  The modifier causes '^' and '$' to match
     respectively (in addition to the normal behavior) the empty string
     after a newline, and the empty string before a newline.  There are
     special character sequences ('\`' and '\'') which always match the
     beginning or the end of the buffer.  In addition, the period
     character does not match a new-line character in multi-line mode.
```

There's no example given.  Upon testing, it's not obvious what this `/M` suffix actually *does*.  It seems to behave like *no* `/M` at all.

So what's a simple significant usage of `/M`?  Where "simplest" means "hello world" simple, nothing that requires very much additional knowledge of other programs, and "signficant" means it should do something noticeable with '/M' that can't be done if it were missing.

Such as, for example, an instance of:

```
seq 10 | sed -n '<code>;/<some regexp>/Mp'
```

...that behaves differently from:

```
seq 10 | sed -n '<code>;/<some regexp>/p'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's the equivalent of the `m` flag in the `perl` regexp operators, or using `(?m)` in perl regexps, or PCREs, (though `gsed`'s `M` flag would also remove the `s` perl flag, as without `M`, `sed`'s `.` matches newline, while with `perl`, you need the `s` flag for `.` to match newline).

These flags only come into play when the pattern space contains more than one line, such as when using `-z`, (to read NUL delimited records), or when adding lines to the pattern space with commands like `G`, `N` or `s`.

```
$ seq 3 | sed 'N;s/$/<foo>/g'
1
2<foo>
3
$ seq 3 | sed 'N;s/$/<foo>/Mg'
1<foo>
2<foo>
3
```

After `N`, the pattern space contains `1<newline>2`. Without `M`, `$` only matches at the end of the pattern space, (after *2*); with `M`, `$` matches both at the end of the first line in that pattern space, (after *1*, but before the newline), *and* at the end the pattern space, (after *2*).

Comment: Good, also I've modified the example in the Q itself to reflect the need for introductory code, (i.e. `G`, `N`, `s`...), *before* the address.   So is the `s` command necessary?  The *info* puts the description of `/M` under 'Addresses > 3.2', and not 'The "s" command > 3.5', so one would think something noticeable would be possible without using "s".

Answer (score 3):

As Stéphane pointed out, this modifier is useful when the pattern space contains more then one line. Here are a few more examples using `'H;1h;$!d;x` which accumulates all lines in the hold buffer and then on last line it exchanges buffers so the whole input is in the pattern space. So with this input:

```
printf %s\\n 'onetwo' 'four' 'fivetwo' | sed 'H;1h;$!d;x;l;d'
```

this is what the pattern space looks like:

```
onetwo\nfour\nfivetwo$
```

`M` might come in handy

- if you need to match the beginning or/and the end of *some or all lines in the pattern space*:

  ```
  printf %s\\n 'onetwo' 'four' 'fivetwo' | sed 'H;1h;$!d;x;s/^/DO/M2;s/$/END/Mg'

  onetwoEND
  DOfourEND
  fivetwoEND
  ```
- if you're trying to find a match that does not span over multiple lines:

  ```
  printf %s\\n 'onetwo' 'four' 'fivetwo' | sed 'H;1h;$!d;x;s/one.*two/MATCH/M'

  MATCH
  four
  fivetwo
  ```
- if you want to manipulate the pattern space on condition that some line in the pattern space starts or ends with a certain pattern (this is an example where it's not used in conjunction with `s`: delete pattern space if one line ends in `ur`):

  ```
  printf %s\\n 'onetwo' 'four' 'fivetwo' | sed 'H;1h;$!d;x;/ur$/Md'
  ```

In all these examples, if you remove `M` the result will be quite different. However, this doesn't mean the above can't be done without `M`, it's just more convenient:

```
s/one.*two/MATCH/M'
```

vs

```
s/one[^\n]*two/MATCH/'
```

or

```
/ur$/Md'
```

vs

```
/ur$\|ur\n/d'
```